# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libtorrent: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, libtorrent

This question has been asked here before but there was no answer.

This is my code:

```
import libtorrent as lt

def get_torrent_info(hash):
    ses = lt.session()
    ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
    params = {
        'save_path': '/',
        'ti': lt.torrent_info(hash),
    }
    h = ses.add_torrent(params)
    while (not h.is_seed()):
        s = h.status()
        print("Seeders: " + str(s.num_seeds))
        print("Leechers: " + str(s.num_peers - s.num_seeds))
        print("File size: " + str(s.total_wanted))
```

I have libtorrent installed using pip. I'm using PyCharm CE IDE and I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\libtorrenttesting\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libtorrent as lt
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libtorrent: The specified module could not be found.
```

I can't find solution anywhere please help. Thanks

Comment: sounds like it is missing the compiled libtorrent library. see https://libtorrent.org/python_binding.html for more info

Comment: idk whats going on exactly, but on linux it seems to work just fine. so ig its a windows issue.